# Book about a Mech pilot trying to fight beings called HuMax

Tags: story-identification, space, mecha

I remember reading this book about a Mech pilot who was trying to fight these beings called HuMax (I think that was the name), and he ended falling in love with a female red-haired one. His mech could merge with him, and turn into liquid or something. The ships in the book were also built into Asteroids as well.

I read it about 2 years ago. I think it had another book coming out around that time

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you add any further information at all, such as when you may have read it?  Anything at all could be useful!

Comment: Oh man, I read it about 2 years ago. I think it had another book coming out around that time.

Comment: @BryceJohnson I've gone ahead and edited that information into your question. If any other details come to mind, please edit them in as well; comments often get deleted without warning, and we don't want to lose any information that might help somebody find your story

Answer (score 4):

*Mecha Corps: A Novel of the Armor Wars* by Brett Patton might be the book you're referring to - the storyline seems to match at least part of the plotline. From the [Kirkus Review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/brett-patton/mecha-rogue/):

> Capt. Matt Lowell is the interstellar Union’s finest Mecha Corps warrior, not least because of his total recall—he calls it his Perfect Record—and his ability to merge his Mecha’s sensory interface, effectively his consciousness, with those of other Mecha pilots. The Mecha are huge, massively powerful, morphing robotic machines developed by Dr. Salvatore Roth to combat the Union's enemy, the Corsairs. Previously, Matt joined the Mecha Corps in order to hunt down and kill Rayder, the genetically engineered HuMax superman who murdered his father. Matt’s latest mission is to destroy a secret lab on a remote planet where more HuMax are being created. But, to his horrified astonishment, he discovers that the Union is behind both the lab and the HuMax, and the mission involves exterminating essentially helpless beings. Unable to stomach the pointless slaughter, he turns rogue and flees with his Mecha to the Corsairs, a vastly more disparate and advanced group than he had been led to believe. And this is just the first of a series of surprises that will cause Matt to question everything he has been told. The narrative moves at a thousand miles an hour, with just enough depth to the backdrop to avoid obvious pitfalls, and makes worthy efforts at character development, though the plotting’s as far-fetched as you might expect, with Matt able to summon up still another battle-winning superpower whenever he needs it.

Cover art:

[image: Cover of *Mecha Corps: A Novel of the Armor Wars*]

Comment: Are there any "huMax" characters?

Comment: Yes, this looks like it. The Humax are genetically engineered superhumans.